# What is the idomatic way to get a single document from Firestore using Go?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm writing a Go service that retrieves a single Firestore Document with a given id. Draft implementation below. The code appears to work. `GetAccount` returns a `map[string]interface{}` which is either `nil` or set to a representation of the document's data.

`go doc firestore.DocumentRef.Get` shows:

> func (d *DocumentRef) Get(ctx context.Context) (_ *DocumentSnapshot, err error)
> Get retrieves the document. If the document does not exist, Get return a
> NotFound error, which can be checked with
>
> ```
>    status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound
> ```
>
> In that case, Get returns a non-nil DocumentSnapshot whose Exists method
> return false and whose ReadTime is the time of the failed read operation.

Why then does a `DocumentSnapshot` also contain an `Exists()` method if `status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound` already indicates its presence?

`go doc firestore.DocumentSnapshot.DataTo` also says:

> If the document does not exist, DataTo returns a NotFound error.

Should I also be checking `status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound` at point B in my code path?

```golang
type srv struct {
    fs *firestore.Client
}

// ...

m, err := srv.GetAccount(ctx, "81199475")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
if m == nil {
    fmt.Println("NOT FOUND")
    os.Exit(0)
}
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", m)

func (s *srv) GetAccount(ctx context.Context, id string) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    docSnap, err := s.fs.Doc("accounts/" + id).Get(ctx)
    if status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound {
        return nil, nil
    }
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var m map[string]interface{}
    if err := docSnap.DataTo(&m); err != nil {
        // Point B
        return nil, err
    }
    return m, nil
}
```

**Update:** It has been pointed out that rather than `GetAccount` returning `nil` to indicate that a document is not found, it would be better to either propagate the underlying Firestore error up the call stack, or provide a custom error.

```golang
var ErrAccountNotFound = errors.New("account/account-not-found")

// ...

if status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound {
    return nil, ErrAccountNotFound
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to check for not found on the error returned from `Get`.

The `DocumentSnapshot.Exists()` method is useful for methods like `GetAll` where multiple snapshots are returned.  These methods do not return an error when an individual document is not found.

Simplify the code by using the `DocumentSnapshot.Data()`:

```
func (s *srv) GetAccount(ctx context.Context, id string) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    docSnap, err := s.fs.Doc("accounts/" + id).Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // Translate firestorm not found to application specific not found.
        if status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound {
            err = ErrAccountNotFound
        }
        return nil, err
    }
    return docSnap.Data(), nil
}
```