# Check error return code from Firestore Get golang sdk

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

I'm trying to create a document in firestore using golang sdk

How can I check the error code returned by the call to DocumentRef.Get() ?

Right now I'm checking if the error contains "NotFound"... Definitely not ideal but can't seem to find anything else

Current Code:

```
doc := firestoreClient.Collection("users").Doc(id)
userSnapshot, err := doc.Get(ctx)
var u *User 
if err != nil {
  isNotFound := strings.Contains(err.Error(), "NotFound")
  if isNotFound {
   // create the document
  }
}
```

Ideally I would like to do something like `if err.Code == NotFound // handle  appropriately`

Or even better, if there's a right pattern for how to GetOrCreate an item in Firestore (using golang)

Comment: You can find some helpers in libraries that helps to decode a standard go error in something useful. Like a function IsNotFoundError or perhaps a interface that you can decode using errors.As(err,&target) or perhaps a very defined error such as ErrNotFound (to be checked with errors.Is(err, specificErr)). Be aware that perform type casting manually may fail if the error is wrapped (also the status.Code(…) will fail on this case).

Answer (score 4):

I just found this in the official docs(https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef.Get)

```
import (
    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)
status.Code(err) == codes.NotFound
```

Thanks for the pointer here! [What is the idomatic way to get a single document from Firestore using Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806911/what-is-the-idomatic-way-to-get-a-single-document-from-firestore-using-go)

Another thread: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/861